# Set Limited for Date Range in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have part of SQL Query.

This SQL Query is no different than other, but only difference is, that `?DATE1::?` is custom built for a web-based reporting tool.

Meaning `?DATE1::?` will give user to pick date from drop down menu. I can use `?DATE1::?` or enter dates manually in query like `05-01-2012`

Here is the where clause:

```
WHERE To_Date(to_char(B.startdatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
  and To_Date(to_char(B.enddatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

How can I change the query so user cannot pick more than 7 days of the date range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this condition aslo

### mysql

```
and To_Date(to_char(B.startdatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
     <= DATE_ADD(To_Date(to_char(B.enddatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

### Oracle

```
and To_Date(to_char(B.startdatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
     <= DateADD('dd' , -7, To_Date(to_char(B.enddatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I added that condition after my original condition. It gives me error `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: One or more errors occurred during processing of command. ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis at ` I checked all parenthesis, they are ok.

Comment: your database is Mysql or Oracle? this is mysql syntax

Comment: Joe, it says ORA-00904:"DATEADD": invalid identifier" but I just figured out the solution by subtracting two dates and getting the difference of 7.  `and To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY') - To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')<=7`

Comment: I am sure your solution, works but may be like you said it might have to do with Mysql syntax. thanks alot for your help, you guided me to solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16648/discussion-between-mogli-and-joe-g-joseph)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking the difference between the picked dates from user after the original query.

Here is original query

```
WHERE To_Date(to_char(B.startdatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
  and To_Date(to_char(B.enddatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Add this condition after above.

`To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY') - To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')<=7`

Final query.

```
WHERE To_Date(to_char(B.startdatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
  and To_Date(to_char(B.enddatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
  and To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY') - To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')<=7
```